# Invoicing from a Residential Address

Tags: invoices

Is there any way I can invoice from a residential address without making it look like its coming from a home?

Comment: Don't cheat, there is no need to.

Answer (score 2):

An address looks like an address. You can't disguise it in any way. If the fact that the address is residential can be determined from merely looking at the address, there's nothing you can do.

You can however, get a PO box or other "box" service to use as a business address.

I, personally, send all business mail to a PO Box so my home address isn't so publicly used.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep some safe distance in having your home address all over things like contracts and so forth.  But occasionally, you may need to receive overnight mail and packages too.

The happy medium for me, for years, has been a Private Mail Box (PMB).  You get one of these at places like the UPS Store.  They can receive overnight packages as well as regular mail, unlike a PO Box.  A PMB is not glaringly obvious like a PO Box in terms of someone seeing an address and making a judgment call on the size or ability of your business, AND it keeps people away from your little slice-of-heaven called home.

Answer (score 0):

As many folk now work from home, and many folk just have a 'home address',  for both personal address and business address, there is little lost in using your home address if your customers know you work from home. If trying to hide home address then you need a Post Office Box number for normal mail, but you will not be able to have courier delivered items delivered to a normal POB address. Sometimes it is useful to rent a desk in an office complex, local industrial estate or such like; if you want to appear with a business address different from your home and you do actually use this address as a work base.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answers involving Post Office and Private Mail Boxes (both good choices I've relied on over the years), you could consider invoicing entirely electronically and leaving your mailing address off of it. It's not necessary as long as you're usually paid electronically as well.