# Is it compulsory to mention my postal address in an invoice I create?

Tags: legal, invoices, software

I've seen [this question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/invoicing-from-a-residential-address) about the confusion on using a residential address, but my question is that since I'm a software professional and I don't expect the company to deliver anything to my postal address and just do a bank transfer of the payment, is it still necessary as a formality or legality for me to mention my postal address in the invoice?

EDIT: This is in India, and I'll be mentioning my email ID, bank account number and phone number on the invoice anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a **legal** business entity in the United States a location (address) **must** be on file and is *public record*.

With the above in mind, what additional harm could come from putting that address on an invoice? Really none.

If you are *not* located in the US but doing business with US companies, and trying to hide your remote location, you may get away with it for a period of time.

Frankly *not* having contact information on invoices would raise suspicions. At least for myself. If you trust me to pay you, why not trust me with an address in case I *prefer* to mail a check.